# Linux Mint 20.2 system-wide Dark Theme in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: linux-mint, chrome

I have Dark Theme set for my Linux Mint 20.2 Uma (I tried different dark themes with the same result: `CBlack`, `Adanta-Nokto`, etc.).
The problem is that Firefox seems to respect the system theme: i.e. sites like https://github.com or https://stackoverflow.com/ are rendered using dark theme when `Using System Theme` is selected in their settings, but in Chrome these sites are still rendered in Light theme. It seems that the Mint's system's theme is not propagated to Chrome no matter what. I tried everything with Chrome: `Classic` theme, `GTK+` theme (with `Just Black` theme installed in Chrome): regardless of the theme settings Chrome still displays the above sites in light theme :-/
The Chrome's interface (just like Firefox) does change its appearance when I change the Mint's system theme between Light and Black but the sites which use `System Settings` seem to respect system settings only in Firefox, but not in Chrome.
Is there some magic setting I can tweak to force Chrome propagate Mint's system theme to rendered site?
I believe both browsers are of the latest version:

- Chrome: 92.0.4515.107
- Firefox: 90.0

Comment: Oh... looks like there is an open issue for it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903